# No Warning or error on duplicate Document Number in Sales Order

Tags: c#, soap, netsuite, suitetalk

I have set Duplicate Number Warnings to **Warn and Block** in Setup -> Accounting -> Accounting Preferences. I have also checked **Treat Warnings and Errors** in Integration Preferences.

What happens is that when I try to create a sales order using NetSuite UI with an already existing Document Number (tranId), NetSuite throws an alert that record with same document number already exists, and blocks the user from creating sales order. On the other hand, if SOAP web service tries to create a sales order with an already existing Document Number, NetSuite creates the Sales Order without returning any warnings or errors.

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix it. I want NetSuite to block teh web service from creating a new sales order if it send an already existing document number for the new sales order to be created.

Comment: Anyone, any help will be great! I have been stuck on this for long.

Comment: Definitely strange behaviour duplicates aren't detected when using SOAP with this setup. You can try to implement some logic in a beforeSubmit to detect duplicates yourself and throw an error when it's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the auto numbering for sales order to allow override ? If that's the case that could be the cause.